# Can we remove the bounty links from deleted answers?

Tags: feature-request, bounties, deleted-answers

[This deleted answer is on a question I am currently bountying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12099210/561731) <sub><sup><sub><sup>(10k+ only)</sup></sub></sup></sub>, the weird part is that there is still a bounty link:

[image: bounty link]

I am afraid to click it too see what happens under the fear that I might accidentally assign a bounty to a deleted answer! (although I am sure there would be a popup preventing me from doing so).

Can we just **remove** the bounty link from a deleted answer all together?

---

**[FOR SCIENCE](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForScience)** I clicked:

[image: for science!]

Comment: Oh, come on, click it! Where's your sense of adventure?

Comment: Go on, click it!

Comment: @YannisRizos haha. True. but then the great answer that **actually** answered my question might _not_ get the bounty if there is a bug.

Comment: @Jim I don't wanna...

Comment: You're close to 41K rep, if you are not going to give away 100 rep for science, you are doing it wrong...

Comment: @YannisRizos true. clicking now. **FOR SCIENCE**!

Comment: Come on, it's **SCIENCE**. Besides, I'm sure you can afford to start a new bounty to reward a *real* answer if you end up having to

Comment: @YannisRizos It looks like we're on the same train of thought here, but you're a car or two ahead of me...

Comment: I clicked **FOR SCIENCE!** :-)

Comment: I was going to downvote for the lack of science, but seeing as how you grew a pair.... +1

Comment: I was hoping it would award the bounty, this would have been more interesting if it was a bug and not a UI thing, but good thing you didn't lose the rep. +1 for science ;)

Comment: Wait, you get a __FOR SCIENCE__ button when you offer a bounty? I've never seen that! Maaaaaaan...

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how this already functions as it should (does not allow awarding the bounty), I don't think a change is warranted.

I *would* suggest rewording the popup, but I think it's fine since it's consistent.

- Trying to accept a deleted answer gives exactly the same message.
- Trying to flag a comment within 5 seconds of voting on a comment indicates you can't vote for comments faster than 1 per 5 seconds.
- (I think?) the same is true for deleting comments.

Since all of these denials refer to the action as voting, this works as expected and is consistent, and I think that no change should be made at all.